# mgt-people-picker selectUsersById is not a function

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using the people picker component from the Microsoft Graph Toolkit, everything has been working for months with v1.3.5 and now I am upgrading to the latest version, v2.1.0, I get an error trying to set an initial user in the picker.

In the HTML I have

```
<mgt-people-picker id="siteOwnersPicker" type="person"></mgt-people-picker>
```

In my TypeScript I am setting an initial user like, where userId is a string with the Guid of the current user

```
const siteOwnersPicker: MgtPeoplePicker = document.querySelector('#siteOwnersPicker')
siteOwnersPicker.selectUsersById([userId]);
```

And I have updated my imports from

```
import { MgtPeoplePicker } from '@microsoft/mgt';
```

to

```
import { MgtPeoplePicker } from '@microsoft/mgt-components';
```

This compiles fine, but at runtime I get the error

```
siteOwnersPicker.selectUsersById is not a function
```

The documentation seems to indicate that the method signature hasn't changed, do I need more imports to bring in the file(s) with the method?

Comment: I'm sure yet, but can you try using the default-selected-user-ids attribute instead? https://stackblitz.com/edit/default-selected?file=index.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.

I was importing the component from

```
import { MgtPeoplePicker } from '@microsoft/mgt-components';
```

when I actually needed to import the component from

```
import { MgtPeoplePicker } from '@microsoft/mgt';
```

don't know why it makes a difference but it does